# Does unanimity of reasons to close matter?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, votes, review

When I look to the close review queue I sometimes find that other voters have given a different reason to close from the one I has eventually decided on. Sometimes though I was only 60:40 in favour of my decision over theirs. I see from the documentation that it is just the overall count of 5 which matters but would it be more helpful to questioners if I went with the majority? I am not proposing to vote for something I definitely disagree obviously, that would be unhelpful and dubious behaviour.

Comment: Confession: one time I clicked on close in the review queue & there were four separate reasons checked. I actually agreed w/ one of the checked reasons, but I clicked the remaining unchecked reason for the novelty of it. (I don't recommend that as an ongoing practice, of course.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that this is common.

I don't find it especially troubling on the whole. If a question is unacceptable on any ground, it doesn't belong. If you throw something out, it is secondary why you do.

At the same time, **good (concise, precise, informative) feedback will tell the OP what was wrong (and help them to do it less often in the future)**. In addition, that feedback **may remind others of the boundaries we have (and, more optimistically, of where they tend to be drawn)**.

But the mix of reasons can imply some inconsistency. Whether the inconsistency is problematic is a deeper question.

Example 1: a question is, according to different voters, too broad **and** unclear. This can often happen with poor questions. Anything close to How should I analyse my data? can be a poor question on both grounds: it is too general without more specifics on the problem and it can be unclear what kind of answer is expected.

Example 2: a question is, according to different voters, too much focused on code in some software **and** deserves migration to Stack Overflow. This is a common clash. Sometimes a visceral "No! this is really a programming question" can disagree with a recommendation to migrate. The need here is to look closely to see if at the heart of the question there is a reproducible code example that would be acceptable on Stack Overflow. That's a tough call unless you have some familiarity with what does and does not go down well there.

Answer (score 4):

In general, just vote the way you think; (weighted) majority rules as to what reason it closes under. If you think that a post could be closed under several different close reasons, post a comment explaining the problems for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about the majority. I accepted Nick's to close the question but yours was also helpful in reassuring me.

Comment: @mdewey If I asked it, I'd have accepted Nick's answer as well.