# Which close option to choose for this question

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I believe this question should be closed:

[Test accuracy much higher than training accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345656/test-accuracy-much-higher-than-training-accuracy)

It's impossible to answer it without looking at the code, so the only reasonable suggestion I can give to the OP is to add code. However, once code is added, the question will become off-topic here and on-topic for Stack Overflow. Right now is not on-topic for SO, so I cannot propose it for migration. What reason for closure should I select?

PS I believe this case is quite different from a preceding, superficially similar question I already asked here

[How to improve the following question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/how-to-improve-the-following-question)

for the following reasons:

- as Nick Cox noted, the other question is so complicated that even on SO it will probably be off-topic (modeling & coding issues are too intertwined). The current question, on the other hand, asks about a well-known, completely solved problem: handwritten digit classification from the MNIST data set.
- the other user was a beginner at her/his first question, and the question was not bad for a first time. Here the user is not an expert for sure, but he's not at his first question either, and the question lacks a lot to be desired, so it should be closed IMO.

Comment: If you do not think there is enough information for even an expert to answer then I would be tempted to say it is Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You might also find this Q&A interesting https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/does-unanimity-of-reasons-to-close-matter as it raises a related question about whether the reason matters.

Comment: @mdewey, why not make that an official answer?

Comment: In reference to a premise in the question - a post containing code is not neccessarly off-topic. This is a common error made by a subset of close-voters. I feel our [help/on-topic] is pretty clear on the matter ("*if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about the implementation of an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain*"). There's certainly room for disagreement about what counts as what for some of the conditions, but no doubt that posts may contain code.

Comment: @Glen_b I think you misunderstood me. I never said that **every** post with code is off-topic. I believe that **this specific question** will become off-topic, once code is added, because the problem (handwritten digit classification on the MNIST dataset) is extremely well-studied, and we know that neural networks implemented in Tensorflow (the plots are clearly from TensorBoard) do well, the split in train/test set is predetermined, thus it's unlikely that the error is statistical. IMO the problem will be of implementation, thus off-topic here. Of course,I can't be sure. But I'm sure the 1/

Comment: 2/ question is impossible to answer in its current form, and all existing answers concentrate on points that are totally irrelevant such as the train/test split, which for this dataset is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers in this Q&A [Does unanimity of reasons to close matter?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/does-unanimity-of-reasons-to-close-matter) throw light on the related issue of whether the reasons for closure matter. The short answer is - they do not.

In the case of the question at issue here it seems from the comments that it falls into a common group of questions where the OP has found something unexpected and seeks enlightenment. This could be a failure of statistical understanding which is clearly on-topic or a problem with data or code. In the latter case it might be on-topic if statistical knowledge is required to answer.

Comment: I believe it's off-topic for the reasons in my comments above, anyway let's see what's happens when/if the OP adds code.

Comment: The idea that the reason given for closing doesn't matter *at all* seems too strong to me, & isn't my reading of the linked thread. I would say that some inconsistency is inevitable & it's OK if people get it wrong sometimes or give what they think is the best reason from several possibilities, even if that differs from others' votes.